# Typescript incorrectly compiles when Vue props are functions instead of data

Tags: typescript, vue.js

It seems that props supplied to a Vue component are not accurately type-checked at compile time.  In the following example

```
// Child
defineProps<{
  isTsError: number[] // Note the child expects an array of numbers
}>()
```

```
// Parent
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]
const strings = ['1', '2', '3']

<Child :isTsError='() => numbers' /> /** Note that a function is passed here */
```

This compiles without issue, however the type for `isTsError` is clearly incorrect.  I can't create a playground with this (I think the vue playground doesn't do full typechecking), but it definitely shows up in my project:

[image]

Weirdly, if we switch `numbers` with `strings`, we do get a TS error, so it it being type-checked.

[image]

Vue is matching both `type` and `() => type` for it's props. In this case, both `number[]` and `() => number[]` can be passed to the same prop.  This only seems to be the case for Vue components, typescript correctly prevents this kind of assignment everywhere else.

Unfortunately, this makes it quite easy to write bugs when we use function getters in Pinia.  Any ideas why this happens, and if it is possible to disable this feature?

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem. "This compiles without issue" - which case is it applicable to? Any error you get in IDE and not on build is specific to IDE, unless proven otherwise. "assume Vue is matching both type and () => type for it's props" - no such problem in Vue in general

Comment: The same problem exists when running tsc (ie, it compiles invalid code), but it's much easier to demonstrate with GUI

Comment: "which case is it applicable to" - neither case should compile, a function is not assignable to an array.  I included both cases to show that type checking is working and will fail to compile in some cases

Comment: You included IDE screenshots, which is not the same as build process. If it occurs in IDE only then consider asking about it, it's probably IDE bug, which are very common and there's nothing much to do about them except reporting them or updating IDE. For build process, template types aren't expected to be checked at all. It depends on your toolchain, which is unknown, usually tsc-vue can be added for template typechecking